# Simple cryptocurrency portfolio rebalancer

Tags: python, python-2.x, api, tkinter, cryptocurrency

### EDIT: the code has been changed significantly since the OP based on the first posted answer and some refactoring. Feedback on the general design of the app itself is still more than welcome. The latest version is [here](https://github.com/shadowk29/BinanceBalance).

I have written a trading bot to interact with Binance in order to turn a crypto portfolio into essentially an ETF - the bot will execute whatever trades are necessary in order to return the percentage allocation of each held coin to a fixed percentage. It makes use of the [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) package to interact with the Binance API. It takes into account cold storage assets (manually entered via a configuration file, more on this below) and assets on the exchange itself. It opens websockets for the user account and updates balances and prices in real time for all assets. Messages pushed from the websockets are stored in a queue and processed sequentially in the main thread. The results are displayed in the following simple GUI (balances shown are not really my balances)

[image]

After you hit dryrun, it calculates the trades needed to bring your portfolio into balance, and displays them:

[image]

There are a couple of options like it out there, but none of them do exactly what I want. Shrimpy.io requires that I give me API keys to a third party and is not open source, while HODLBOT only uses market orders, which I am not overly comfortable with. My code allows entirely local execution, and API keys are not stored anywhere except in RAM as the code executes (is this a security risk?).

I would like to get feedback on style, since I'm a relatively novice programmer with anything involving interacting with a web API. Any suggestions for performance boosts are certainly welcome, since the `dryrun()` function currently takes a few seconds to execute.

I currently have rebalancing split into two manual steps - executing sells, and executing buys. I did this for simplicity, since I am as yet not quite familiar with how the API reports trades completed, but I plan to implement a single rebalance step in the future.

Finally, I have not yet actually tested the `execute_sells()` and `execute_buys()` functions. They mirror the `dryrun()` function so they should work, but I am unsure how to go about testing them properly without actually just going for it and trading assets on the exchange. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

If anyone decides to run it, you can use this example, saved as a simple `.csv` file called `allocations.csv` in the same folder as the script to do so.

```
coin,fixed_balance,allocation
BTC,0.5,13
ETH,2,13
XLM,1000,10
LTC,3,10
ZRX,200,10
THETA,1000,7
NANO,20,7
IOTA,50,5
BNB,2,5
NEO,1,5
OMG,10,5
XMR,3,5
XRP,50,5
```

The code is below. If you prefer to see it on Github, it's [here](https://github.com/shadowk29/BinanceBalance/tree/706413eed37506fa2745f00f471a8e0097d40a9d) as well.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.enums import *
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
import Queue
from twisted.internet import reactor
import os.path

def round_decimal(num, decimal):
    """
    Round a given floating point number 'num' to the nearest integer
    multiple of another floating point number 'decimal' smaller than
    'num' and return it as a string with up to 8 decimal places,
    dropping any trailing zeros.
    """
    if decimal > 0:
        x = np.round(num/decimal, 0)*decimal
    else:
        x = np.round(num, 8)
    return '{0:.8f}'.format(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')


class BalanceGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, coins):
        """ Initialize all GUI widgets """
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.parent = parent
        parent.deiconify()
        self.coins = coins
        self.coins_base = coins
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.trades_placed = 0
        self.trades_completed = 0
        self.trade_currency = 'BTC'
        self.trades = []
        self.headers = self.column_headers()
        coincount = len(coins)
        self.timer = 1000/(5*coincount)

        #portfolio display
        self.portfolio_view = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text='Portfolio')
        self.portfolio_view.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.portfolio = ttk.Treeview(self.portfolio_view)
        self.portfolio['columns']=('Stored','Exchange', 'Target','Actual', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Action', 'Status')
        for label in self.portfolio['columns']:
            if label == 'Status':
                self.portfolio.column(label, width=250)
            elif label == 'Action':
                self.portfolio.column(label, width=150)
            else:
                self.portfolio.column(label, width=100)
            self.portfolio.heading(label, text=label)
        self.portfolio.grid(row=0,column=0)

        #options display
        self.controls_view = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text='Controls')
        self.controls_view.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        key_label = tk.Label(self.controls_view, text='API Key')
        key_label.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        secret_label = tk.Label(self.controls_view, text='API Secret')
        secret_label.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.key_entry = tk.Entry(self.controls_view, show='*')
        self.key_entry.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.secret_entry = tk.Entry(self.controls_view, show='*')
        self.secret_entry.grid(row=0, column=3,sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.login = tk.Button(self.controls_view, text='Login', command = self.api_enter)
        self.login.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)



        self.ordertype = tk.StringVar()
        self.ordertype.set('Market')
        self.orderopt = tk.OptionMenu(self.controls_view, self.ordertype, 'Market', 'Market-Limit')
        self.orderopt.grid(row=1, column=0, stick=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.orderopt['state'] = 'disabled'

        self.dryrun_button = tk.Button(self.controls_view, text='Dry Run', command=self.dryrun, state='disabled')
        self.dryrun_button.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.sell_button = tk.Button(self.controls_view, text='Execute Sells', command=self.execute_sells, state='disabled')
        self.sell_button.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.buy_button = tk.Button(self.controls_view, text='Execute Buys', command=self.execute_buys, state='disabled')
        self.buy_button.grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)


    def on_closing(self):
        """ Check that all trades have executed before starting the save and exit process """
        if self.trades_placed > 0 and self.trades_completed < self.trades_placed:
            if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit', 'Not all trades have completed, some trade data might not be recorded. Quit anyway?'):
                self.save_and_quit()
        else:
            self.save_and_quit()

    def save_and_quit(self):
        """
        If trades have been executed in the current session, save them to file. Stop all websockets and exit the GUI.
        """
        if len(self.trades) > 0:
            df = pd.DataFrame(self.trades)
            if os.path.isfile('trade_history.csv'):
                with open('trade_history.csv','a') as f:
                    df.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False, index=False)
            else:
                with open('trade_history.csv','w') as f:
                    df.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=True, index=False)
        try:
            self.bm.close()
            reactor.stop()
        except AttributeError:
            self.parent.destroy()
        else:
            self.parent.destroy()


    def api_enter(self):
        """ Log in to Binance with the provided credentials, update user portfolio and start listening to price and account update websockets. """
        api_key = self.key_entry.get()
        self.key_entry.delete(0,'end')
        api_secret = self.secret_entry.get()
        self.secret_entry.delete(0,'end')


        self.key_entry['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.secret_entry['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.login['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.dryrun_button['state'] = 'normal'
        self.orderopt['state'] = 'normal'

        self.client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
        status = self.client.get_system_status()

        self.populate_portfolio()
        self.start_websockets()

    def start_websockets(self):
        """ Start websockets to get price updates for all coins in the portfolio, trade execution reports, and user account balance updates. Start the message queue processor. """
        self.bm = BinanceSocketManager(self.client)
        self.bm.start()
        trade_currency = self.trade_currency
        symbols = self.coins['symbol'].tolist()
        symbols.remove(trade_currency+trade_currency)

        self.sockets = {}
        for symbol in symbols:
            self.sockets[symbol] = self.bm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(symbol, self.queue_msg)
        self.sockets['user'] = self.bm.start_user_socket(self.queue_msg)
        self.parent.after(10, self.process_queue)

    def populate_portfolio(self):
        """ Get all symbol info from Binance needed to populate user portfolio data and execute trades """
        self.coins = self.coins_base
        self.portfolio.delete(*self.portfolio.get_children())
        exchange_coins = []
        trade_currency = self.trade_currency
        self.trade_coin = trade_currency

        for coin in self.coins['coin']:
            pair = coin+trade_currency
            balance = self.client.get_asset_balance(asset=coin)
            if coin != trade_currency:
                price = float(self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol = pair)['price'])
                symbolinfo = self.client.get_symbol_info(symbol=pair)['filters']
                row = {'coin': coin, 'exchange_balance': float(balance['free']),
                   'minprice': float(symbolinfo[0]['minPrice']), 'maxprice': float(symbolinfo[0]['maxPrice']), 'ticksize': float(symbolinfo[0]['tickSize']),
                   'minqty': float(symbolinfo[1]['minQty']), 'maxqty': float(symbolinfo[1]['maxQty']), 'stepsize': float(symbolinfo[1]['stepSize']),                   
                   'minnotional': float(symbolinfo[2]['minNotional']), 'symbol': pair, 'askprice' : price, 'bidprice': price, 'price': price}
            else:
                fixed_balance = self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin]['fixed_balance']
                row = {'coin': coin, 'exchange_balance': float(balance['free']),
                   'minprice': 0, 'maxprice': 0, 'ticksize': 0,
                   'minqty': 0, 'maxqty': 0, 'stepsize': 0,                   
                   'minnotional': 0, 'symbol': coin+coin, 'askprice' : 1.0, 'bidprice': 1.0, 'price': 1.0}
            exchange_coins.append(row)
        exchange_coins = pd.DataFrame(exchange_coins)
        self.coins = pd.merge(self.coins, exchange_coins, on='coin', how='outer')

        self.coins['value'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: row.price*(row.exchange_balance + row.fixed_balance), axis=1)
        self.total = np.sum(self.coins['value'])
        self.coins['actual'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: 100.0*row.value/self.total, axis=1)

        i = 0
        for row in self.coins.itertuples():
            self.portfolio.insert("" , i, iid=row.coin, text=row.coin,
                                  values=(round_decimal(row.fixed_balance, row.stepsize), round_decimal(row.exchange_balance, row.stepsize),
                                          '{0} %'.format(row.allocation), '{0:.2f} %'.format(row.actual), round_decimal(row.price, row.ticksize),round_decimal(row.price, row.ticksize),'','Waiting'))
            i += 1

    def queue_msg(self, msg):
        """ Whenever a weboscket receives a message, check for errors. If an error occurs, restart websockets. If no error, add it to the message queue. """
        if msg['e'] == 'error':
            self.bm.close()
            reactor.stop()
            self.start_websockets()
        else:
            self.queue.put(msg)

    def process_queue(self):
        """ Check for new messages in the queue periodically, and reroute them to the appropriate handler. Recursively calls itself to perpetuate the process. """
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get(0)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if msg['e'] == '24hrTicker':
                self.update_price(msg)
            elif msg['e'] == 'outboundAccountInfo':
                self.update_balance(msg)
            elif msg['e'] == 'executionReport':
                self.update_trades(msg)
        self.master.after(self.timer, self.process_queue)

    def update_trades(msg):
        """ Update balances whenever a partial execution occurs """
        coin = msg['s'][:-len(self.trade_coin)]
        savemsg = {self.headers[key] : value for key, value in msg.items()}
        percent = 100.0*float(savemsg['cumulative_filled_quantity'])/float(savemsg['order_quantity'])
        if percent < 100.0:
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value = 'In Progress: {0:.2f}%'.format(percent))
        else:
            self.trades_completed += 1
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value = 'Completed')
        self.trades.append(savemsg)    


    def update_balance(self, msg):
        """ Update user balances internally and on the display whenever an account update message is received. """
        balances = msg['B']
        for balance in balances:
            coin = balance['a']
            exchange_balance = balance['f'] + balance['l']
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Exchange', value=round_decimal(exchange_balance,self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'stepsize'].values[0]))
            self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'exchange_balance'] = exchange_balance
            ask = self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'askprice'].values[0]
            value = (self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'exchange_balance'].values[0] + self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'fixed_balance'].values[0])*ask
            self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'value'] = value

        self.total = np.sum(self.coins['value']) 
        self.coins['actual'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: 100.0*row.value/self.total, axis=1)
        for row in self.coins.itertuples():
            coin = row.coin
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Actual', value='{0:.2f}%'.format(self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'actual'].values[0]))

    def update_price(self, msg):
        """ Update symbol prices and user allocations internally and on the display whenever a price update is received. """
        coin = msg['s'][:-len(self.trade_currency)]
        ask = float(msg['a'])
        bid = float(msg['b'])

        self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Ask', value=round_decimal(ask,self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'ticksize'].values[0]))
        self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'askprice'] = ask

        self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Bid', value=round_decimal(bid,self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'ticksize'].values[0]))
        self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'bidprice'] = bid

        value = (self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'exchange_balance'].values[0] + self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'fixed_balance'].values[0])*ask
        self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'value'] = value

        self.total = np.sum(self.coins['value'])

        self.coins['actual'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: 100.0*row.value/self.total, axis=1)

        for row in self.coins.itertuples():
            coin = row.coin
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Actual', value='{0:.2f}%'.format(self.coins.loc[self.coins['coin'] == coin, 'actual'].values[0]))


    def dryrun(self):
        """ Determine approximate trades which must occur in order to rebalance, and report them to the user. Place test orders to ensure compliance with Binance API """
        self.sell_button['state'] = 'normal'
        self.coins['difference'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: (row.allocation - row.actual)/100.0 * self.total/row.price,axis=1)
        for row in self.coins.itertuples():
            status = ''
            coin = row.coin
            pair = coin+self.trade_coin
            balance = row.exchange_balance
            actual = row.actual
            dif = row.difference
            qty = np.absolute(dif)
            if dif < 0:
                side = SIDE_SELL
                price = row.bidprice
            else:
                side = SIDE_BUY
                price = row.askprice
            if side == SIDE_SELL and qty > balance and coin != self.trade_coin:
                status = 'Insufficient funds for complete rebalance'
            action = 'None'
            if coin == self.trade_coin:
                action = 'Ready'
            elif qty < row.minqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too small'
            elif qty > row.maxqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too large'
            elif qty * price < row.minnotional:
                action = 'Trade value too small'
            else:
                action = '{0} {1}'.format(side, round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))

                trade_type = self.ordertype.get()
                trade_currency = self.trade_coin
                try:
                    if trade_type == 'Market-Limit':
                        order = self.client.create_test_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                                                             timeInForce = TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize),
                                                             price = round_decimal(price, row.ticksize))
                    elif trade_type == 'Market':
                        order = self.client.create_test_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))                    
                except Exception as e:
                    status = e
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value=status)
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Action', value=action)


    def execute_sells(self):
        """ Execute any sell orders required to rebalance the portfolio, and enable buy orders """
        self.sell_button['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.buy_button['state'] = 'normal'
        self.coins['difference'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: (row.allocation - row.actual)/100.0 * self.total/row.price,axis=1)
        sellcoins = self.coins[self.coins['difference'] < 0]
        for row in sellcoins.itertuples():
            coin = row.coin
            balance = row.exchange_balance

            pair = coin+self.trade_coin
            actual = row.actual
            dif = row.difference
            qty = np.absolute(dif)
            side = SIDE_SELL
            price = row.bidprice
            if qty > balance:
                qty = balance
            action = 'None'
            if coin == self.trade_coin:
                action = 'Ready'
            elif qty < row.minqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too small'
            elif qty > row.maxqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too large'
            elif qty * price < row.minnotional:
                action = 'Trade value too small'
            else:
                action = '{0} {1}'.format(side, round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))

                trade_type = self.ordertype.get()
                trade_currency = self.trade_coin
                try:
                    if trade_type == 'Market-Limit':
                        order = self.client.create_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                                                             timeInForce = TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize),
                                                             price = round_decimal(price, row.ticksize))
                    elif trade_type == 'Market':
                        order = self.client.create_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))                    
                except Exception as e:
                    self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value=e)
                else:
                    self.trades_placed += 1
                    self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value='Trade Placed')
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Action', value=action)

    def execute_buys(self):
        """ Execute any sell orders required to rebalance the portfolio """
        self.buy_button['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.coins['difference'] = self.coins.apply(lambda row: (row.allocation - row.actual)/100.0 * self.total/row.price,axis=1)
        buycoins = self.coins[self.coins['difference'] > 0]
        for row in buycoins.itertuples():
            coin = row.coin
            balance = row.exchange_balance

            pair = coin+self.trade_coin
            actual = row.actual
            dif = row.difference
            qty = np.absolute(dif)
            side = SIDE_BUY
            price = row.askprice
            action = 'None'
            if coin == self.trade_coin:
                action = 'Ready'
            elif qty < row.minqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too small'
            elif qty > row.maxqty:
                action = 'Trade quantity too large'
            elif qty * price < row.minnotional:
                action = 'Trade value too small'
            else:
                action = '{0} {1}'.format(side, round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))

                trade_type = self.ordertype.get()
                trade_currency = self.trade_coin
                try:
                    if trade_type == 'Market-Limit':
                        order = self.client.create_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                                                             timeInForce = TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize),
                                                             price = round_decimal(price, row.ticksize))
                    elif trade_type == 'Market':
                        order = self.client.create_order(symbol = pair,
                                                             side = side,
                                                             type = ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
                                                             quantity = round_decimal(qty, row.stepsize))                    
                except Exception as e:
                    self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value=e)
                else:
                    self.trades_placed += 1
                    self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Status', value='Trade Placed')
            self.portfolio.set(coin, column='Action', value=action)


    def column_headers(self):
        """ define human readable aliases for the headers in trade execution reports. """
        return {'e': 'event_type',
                'E': 'event_time',
                's': 'symbol',
                'c': 'client_order_id',
                'S': 'side',
                'o': 'type',
                'f': 'time_in_force',
                'q': 'order_quantity',
                'p': 'order_price',
                'F': 'iceberg_quantity',
                'g': 'ignore_1',
                'C': 'original_client_order_id',
                'x': 'current_execution_type',
                'X': 'current_order_status',
                'r': 'order_reject_reason',
                'i': 'order_id',
                'l': 'last_executed_quantity',
                'z': 'cumulative_filled_quantity',
                'L': 'last_executed_price',
                'n': 'commission_amount',
                'N': 'commission_asset',
                'T': 'transction_time',
                't': 'trade_id',
                'I': 'ignore_2',
                'w': 'order_working',
                'm': 'maker_side',
                'M': 'ignore_3'}

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    portfolio = 'allocation.csv' 
    coins = pd.read_csv(portfolio)
    BalanceGUI(root, coins).grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.wm_title('BinanceBalance')
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Future plans involve allowing the bot to run on a timer or maybe when the portfolio reaches a certain imbalance threshold and maybe adding support for trading pairs other than those mediated through BTC, but for now I'd like to get some feedback on the manual, minimalist version before I get too deep into features that aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: `Simple cryocurrency portfolio rebalancer` Is cryo currency viable during summer?

Comment: @yuri Oh. I get it. Fixed haha. There's probably a joke about "cold storage" in there somewhere.

Comment: @yuri missed opportunity: "yes, but it gets liquidated". Dammit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style recommendations:

   - Top-level function and class definitions should be preceded by two blank lines. In a class, method definitions should be separated by a single blank line. Avoid using blank lines too liberally; doing so will hurt readability.
   - Leave whitespace between operators like `=`, `+` and `,`. In function calls, keyword parameters / values should not be separated by whitespace.
   - Don't mix single and double quotes.
   - Your longest line is 198 characters long! The maximum line length is 79 (or 80) characters, and 73 for flowing text (comments and docstrings). If you want to, you can relax this and set a limit of 100 characters, but 198 is absurd.
2. Catching `Exception` is almost always too broad. You don't, for example, want to catch a keyboard interrupt (`KeyboardInterrupt`). It would be best to take a look at the Binance docs, specifically [`binance.client.Client.create_order()`](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.create_order), to see what exceptions it can raise.
3. Don't use `0` for implicit falsy values. From the Zen of Python:

   > Explicit is better than implicit.

   So:

   ```
   self.queue.get(0)
   ```

   ... should be:

   ```
   self.queue.get(False)
   ```
4. Checking for empty containers should be done by implicit boolean comparison:

   ```
   if len(self.trades) > 0:
   ```

   ... should be:

   ```
   if self.trades:
   ```

Comment: I believe I have addressed all of your comments: https://github.com/shadowk29/BinanceBalance/blob/master/binance-balance.py Would you mind taking a quick look through to confirm? There are a few places where lines are still longer than they should be, but I don't see on obvious breakpoint so I left them as-is for now.